# How to implement dialog fragment from Recyclerview Adapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-dialogfragment

Here cannot resolve the method show. How to fix it. I want to call `DialogFragmnent` from recycled view. How to resolve this show method from `Recyclerview` adapter. I want to call this dialog fragment during click on item list of recycled view. How is it possible?

```
public class AppointmentServiceListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AppointmentServiceListAdapter.ViewHolder>
    {

        Context mContext;
        SessionManager mSessionManager;
        ArrayList<AppointServiceList> appointArrayList;
        ArrayList<AppointServiceDetails> appointservicedetailsArrayList;
        AppointmentServiceDetailsAdapter appointmentServiceDetailsAdapter;

        public AppointmentServiceListAdapter(Context mContext,ArrayList<AppointServiceList> appointArrayList,ArrayList<AppointServiceDetails> appointservicedetailsArrayList)
        {
            this.mContext = mContext;
            this.appointArrayList = appointArrayList;
            mSessionManager= new SessionManager(mContext);
            this.appointservicedetailsArrayList = appointservicedetailsArrayList;
            appointmentServiceDetailsAdapter = new AppointmentServiceDetailsAdapter(mContext,appointservicedetailsArrayList);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public AppointmentServiceListAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view               = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_my_appointmentlist,parent,false);
            AppointmentServiceListAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder = new AppointmentServiceListAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
            return viewHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position)
        {
                holder.bookingDate.setText(appointArrayList.get(position).getDate());
                holder.bookingEmp.setText(appointArrayList.get(position).getEmpName());
                holder.bookingSlot.setText(appointArrayList.get(position).getSlot());
                holder.rv_appoint_servicelist.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext));
                holder.rv_appoint_servicelist.setAdapter(appointmentServiceDetailsAdapter);
                holder.lin_intent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        FragmentManager mfFragmentManager = ((Activity)mContext).getFragmentManager();
                        AppointmentBookingDialogFragment appointmentBookingDialogFragment = new AppointmentBookingDialogFragment(mContext,position);
                        appointmentBookingDialogFragment.show(mfFragmentManager,"appointmentdialog");
                    }
                });



                appointmentServiceDetailsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount()
        {
            return appointArrayList.size();
        }

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        {
            TextView bookingDate,bookingSlot,bookingEmp;
            RecyclerView rv_appoint_servicelist;
            LinearLayout lin_intent;

            public ViewHolder(View itemView)
            {
                super(itemView);
                bookingDate            = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.bookingDate);
                bookingSlot            = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.bookingSlot );
                bookingEmp             = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.bookingEmp);
                rv_appoint_servicelist = (RecyclerView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.rv_appoint_servicelist);
                lin_intent             = (LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.lin_intent);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your activity is extending `AppCompatActivity` and your `AppointmentBookingDialogFragment` is subclass of `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment`

Replace this code with below one `FragmentManager mfFragmentManager = ((Activity)mContext).getFragmentManager();` and also make sure your adapter have right import `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager` not the import `android.app.FragmentManager`

```
FragmentManager mfFragmentManager = ((AppCompatActivity)mContext).getSupportFragmentManager();
```

For your reference have modified your code like below

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager mfFragmentManager = ((AppCompatActivity)mContext).getSupportFragmentManager();
AppointmentBookingDialogFragment appointmentBookingDialogFragment = new AppointmentBookingDialogFragment(mContext,position);
appointmentBookingDialogFragment.show(mfFragmentManager,"appointmentdialog");
```